# ngrx action is called without calling it in effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, action, ngrx, effects

I have made a effect to load data and actions to load, load success and load failure.
Effect is working but it calls both actions(success, failure) but I returned just load success.
If I move failure reducer above success it calls first failure and then success and similary if i switch them.
I didn`t dispatch any of them somewhere else.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
loadFilteredElements$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(loadFilteredElements),
        switchMap((action) => this.elementsService.getFilteredElementsForProject(action.filter)),
        map((data) => loadFilteredElementsSuccess(data.values!))
    )
);
```

```js
on(ElementActions.loadFilteredElementsSuccess, (state: ElementState, { elements }) =>{ 
    console.log('succes action');

    return ({
    ...state,
    elements: elements,
    error: undefined,
    status: StatusEnum.success,
})}),
on(ElementActions.loadFilteredElementsFailure, (state: ElementState, { error }) =>{
    console.log('failure');

    return  ({
    ...state,
    status: StatusEnum.error,
    error: error,
})}),
on(ElementActions.changeElementFilter, (state: ElementState, { filter }) =>{
    console.log('changefilter');

    return ({
    ...state,
    filter: filter,
})})
```

```js
export const loadFilteredElements = createAction('[Element[]] load elements from server', (filter: ElementFilter) => ({
    filter,
}));

export const loadFilteredElementsSuccess = createAction(
    '[Elements[] API] elements succesfully loaded',
    (elements: AppElement[]) => ({ elements })
);

export const loadFilteredElementsFailure = createAction(
    '[Elements[] API] elements succesfully loaded',
    (error: ResponseResultEnum) => ({ error })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your failure action is using the same type as your success action, so infact you have declared the same action twice.

Change

```js
export const loadFilteredElementsSuccess = createAction(
    '[Elements[] API] elements succesfully loaded',
    (elements: AppElement[]) => ({ elements })
);

export const loadFilteredElementsFailure = createAction(
    '[Elements[] API] elements succesfully loaded',
    (error: ResponseResultEnum) => ({ error })
);
```

to

```js
export const loadFilteredElementsSuccess = createAction(
    '[Elements[] API] elements succesfully loaded',
    (elements: AppElement[]) => ({ elements })
);

export const loadFilteredElementsFailure = createAction(
    '[Elements[] API] elements failed to load',
    (error: ResponseResultEnum) => ({ error })
);
```

Comment: Oh no. . . Thanks a lot. But how is it possible that bad type can cause such an issue. If the succes and failure actions has different names. . .

Answer (score 0):

The NgRx `Effect` dispatches an action by default, if you didn't change that.

So, any action returned from the effect stream (using `map` operator) is then dispatched back to the `Store`.

As described in [@ngrx/effects](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#writing-effects) docs:

> Metadata is attached to the observable streams using the createEffect function. The metadata is used to register the streams that are subscribed to the store. Any action returned from the effect stream is then dispatched back to the Store.

To change this behavior, add `{ dispatch: false }` to the `createEffect` function as the second argument, like the following:

```js
loadFilteredElements$ = createEffect(
    () =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(loadFilteredElements),
            switchMap((action) => this.elementsService.getFilteredElementsForProject(action.filter)),
            map((data) => loadFilteredElementsSuccess(data.values!))
        ),
    { dispatch: false }
);
```

Comment: Yes thats how I was thinking about that. But I want to dispatch succes if response is ok and failure if response is error. In this cas I dont dispatch anything. I the code I posted I dispetch loadElemetSucces but if i look to log both actions was called success and failure thats the problem. I don`t need dispatch : false. . .